# jQuery: setting a form state from a params string

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, cookies, parameters

I have a requirement to save a form's state in a cookie, so the setting can be remembered for a given user.  I'm using jQuery, and my plan is thus:

```
Saving:
//generate a param string from the form settings
var paramString = $.param($("#my-form").serializeArray());
//save it to a cookie
$.cookie("my-form-cookie", paramString);

Loading:
//get the cookie value
var savedParams = $.cookie("my-form-cookie")
//turn it into an object with field names as keys and field values as values
var formObject = JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(savedParams).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}')
//go through this, modifying the form
...
```

This is the missing piece of the puzzle at the moment.

What i was planning on doing was something like this (pseudocode rather than js)

```
for every key/value pair (key,value)
  find element(s) with name = key
  if there's more than one, it's probably radio buttons/checkboxes:
    - check the one with value = value and uncheck the rest
  if there's exactly one
    - set the value = value
```

Before i set off to write a function for doing this, which takes a form id and a param-style string, i'm thinking someone else has either a) done this, in a more thorough way than i would, or b) tried it and decided it's a bad idea, or doomed to fail.

Anyone got any input, on a) or b) ?

thanks!  max

Comment: Instead of a cookie, could you send this data down from the server from information you get from the cookie?  If you can do this, then you could populate the form with some mvvm framework (angular, knockout, &c).

Comment: Erik - yes, that's actually what i'm doing already.  But it's complicated - i really want to save and load the state on the client, using js.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i ended up doing.  It's got definite scope for being cleaned up, but it seems to work ok.  It handles nested parameters, and array-style parameters.  You can add a class of `dont-cookie` to form elements which you don't want to be set from the cookie, when it's used to restore the state.

```
//convert the form's state to a params string and save it to a cookie with the 
//name form-<form_id>.  Note that all form values are saved to 
//the cookie, even the ones with .dont-save (these are ignored on load though)
function saveFormStateToCookie(form, cookie){
  //jqueryfy the form if it's not already
  if(typeof(form) != "object")
    form = $(form);  
  if(typeof(cookie) == "undefined")
    cookie = formCookieName(form);    
  //console.log("using cookie name '"+cookie+"'");

  var paramString = $.param(form.serializeArray());
  //console.log("saving: (unescaped)\n"+unescape(paramString));
  $.cookie(cookie, paramString, {path: "/"});
}


function loadFormStateFromCookie(form, cookie){
  //jqueryfy form if it's not already
  if(typeof(form) != "object")
    form = $(form);  
  if(typeof(cookie) == "undefined")
    cookie = formCookieName(form);
  //console.log("using cookie name '"+cookie+"'");
  //get the cookie value
  var paramString = $.cookie(cookie);
  //console.log("loaded:(unescaped)\n"+unescape(paramString));
  //what if it's blank, or the cookie doesn't exist?
  if(paramString){
    //turn it into an object with field names as keys and field values as values
    var formObject = QueryStringToHash(paramString);
    var elements, checkableElements, matchedElement;
    var changedElements = [];
    //set all checkboxes and radio buttons in the form to be blank
    form.find("[type='radio'], [type='checkbox']").not(".dont-cookie").removeAttr('checked');
    //go through this, modifying the form  
    $.each(formObject, function(name,values){
      //note: value can be an array of values or a string.  Let's make it always an array, to be consistent
      if(typeof(values) === "string"){
        values = [values]; 
      }
      //find all elements matching the name.
      elements = form.find("[name='"+name+"']").not(".dont-cookie");

      if(elements.size() > 0){   
        //iterate over values
        $.each(values, function(i,value){
          //is there a checkbox/radio with this value,  which ISN'T in changedElements? 
          var checkboxes = elements.filter("[type='radio'], [type='checkbox']").filter("[value='"+value+"'], [value='"+value.replace(/\+/g, " ")+"']").filter(function(i){ return  changedElements.indexOf($(this)) === -1});
          //yes there is - check it and add it to changedElements
          if(checkboxes.size() > 0){
            $.each(checkboxes, function(j,checkbox){
              checkbox = $(checkbox);
              checkbox.attr("checked", "checked");
              changedElements.push(checkbox);
            });
          } else {
            //THIS IS WIPING OVER ALL THE CHECKBOXES:  WE NEED TO JUST DO IT TO NON-CHECKBOXES
            //no there isn't: set their val to value, then add them to changedElements
            $.each(elements.not("[type='radio'], [type='checkbox']"), function(i, element){
              element = $(element);
              element.val(value);
              changedElements.push(element);
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  } else {
    //console.log("Couldn't find a cookie matching "+cookie);
  }
}
```